# Detecting the height of a ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, layout

Just throwing this out there to see if anybody has some ideas:

Basically, I'm building a packing slip for our shipping application.  The top half will be the package contents, while the bottom half will be a return shipping label.

Per our business requirements, if the package contents listview takes up over half the page, then it needs to expand to take up the entire page height, and we print the return label on a separate page.

My question is, how would I be able to tell what the height of the ListView is?  Granted, I'm still in the early/prototype stages, but would it go something like this?

1. Define a min height for the ListView
2. Bind the data to the ListView
3. Check ListView height.  If it equals the min height, then I'm good. 
   If it's > than the min height, set it to take up the entire page,
   and print the return label on a new page

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to force render list as below:

```
lvItems.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
lvItems.Arrange(new Rect(lvItems.DesiredSize));
var calculatedHeight= lvItems.ActualHeight;
```